# UIWebView Interpreting UTF-8 latin characters incorrectly

Tags: character-encoding, uiwebview

I looked at the JSON returned from there server. When I look at it in a browser, I assume what I see is the raw encoding, which contains strings that look like this:

> del mecenazgo para la conservaci\u00c3\u00b3n y divulgaci\u00c3\u00b3n
>   del arte cl\u00c3\u00a1sico
>
> Entrada general y gu\u00c3\u00ada del Museo

I assume then that my display of these strings is incorrect because the incoming JSON has not been encoded properly.

I looked at the original source data (a scraped web page), and the coding looks more like this, along with what I see displayed in a UIWebView:

> Jerónimo (correct) = Jer\u00c3\u00b3nimo (incorrect) = JerÃ³nimo (as incorrectly displayed)
>   doméstica (correct) = dom\u00c3\u00a9stica (incorrect) = domÃ©stica (as incorrectly displayed)

I looked at some UTF-8 codes for these latin characters. 0xc3,0xb3 is oacute (ó) and 0xc3,0xa9 is eacute (é). But the UIWebView doesn't convert these properly. (The head contains a meta tag with the charset=UTF-8.) What can I do about it?

Comment: Right now I scan the C string for N-tuples that fit a pattern and replace them with the corrected pattern. That's all I have right now, but it's working.